# Extending the Table Class in Qooxdoo doesn't works?

Tags: extend, qooxdoo

I have a custom class that looks like this:

```
qx.Class.define('test.Table2', {
extend: qx.ui.table.Table,

construct: function(model){
    this.base(arguments);
    }
});
```

What happens?

If I use the qx.ui.table.Table with a model it shows data. If I change to test.Table2 then it shows an empty table with empty col names too. only a little bar.

How do I extend it properly?

Comment: Cross-post from the qooxdoo mailing list. You should really stop these cross-posts. You will only get answers over one channel, and as you are on the mailing list anyway, stick with it.

Comment: ok (: sorry, I didn't new was bad. I will stick to the qooxdoo forum then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass all parameters to base class constructor:

```
this.base(arguments, model);
```